# Merge two SAFEARRAY's - SafeArrayPutElement memory access violation

Tags: com, interop, safearray

I am getting some memory access violation while execute the following code:

```
UINT cDims = 1;

SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
long lLbound = 0;
long lUbound = 0;

rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;

rgsabound[0].cElements = pList1->rgsabound[0].cElements + pList2->rgsabound[0].cElements;


SAFEARRAY* mergeResult = SafeArrayCreate(VT_DISPATCH, cDims, reinterpret_cast<SAFEARRAYBOUND*>(rgsabound));

// Obtain bounds information of the SAFEARRAY. 
SafeArrayGetLBound(pList2, 1, &lLbound);
SafeArrayGetUBound(pList2, 1, &lUbound);

long lDimSize = lUbound - lLbound + 1;

    GoldMineConstantContactCOM::IBounceActivityPtr ptrActivity;

    SafeArrayCopy(pList1, &mergeResult);

    rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
    rgsabound[0].cElements = pList1->rgsabound[0].cElements + pList2->rgsabound[0].cElements;

    SafeArrayRedim(mergeResult, rgsabound);

    for (int i = 0; i < lDimSize; i++)
    {
        long rgIndices[1];
        rgIndices[0] = i;

        HRESULT hRes2 = SafeArrayGetElement(pList2, rgIndices, &ptrActivity);

        rgIndices[0] = rgIndices[0] + pList1->rgsabound[0].cElements;

        HRESULT hRes = SafeArrayPutElement(mergeResult, rgIndices, (void*)&ptrActivity);                
    }

    return mergeResult;
```

The message I got is: Unhandled exception at 0x774115de : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

Any help will be very helpful!

Thanks in advance

Regards,
   Fabian

Comment: You could use ATL's CComSafeArray, it can add two arrays: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z6f4d3y5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `&` in `SafeArrayCopy(pList1, &mergeResult);` raised suspicions that the documentation confirmed: The function does not copy from the source array to your allocated one, it overwrites the pointer (leaking it) with a new array of the same dimension. However, your call to `SafeArrayRedim` appears to take care of (part of) the problem.

Also, you take care of retrieving the lower bound of pList2, but you don't use it during the actual copy.

Then, I'm not sure the smart pointer is used exactly right. I think maybe you should put its declaration inside the loop.

Finally, I think I've found the real culprit: The documentation of `SafeArrayPutElement` say:

> The variant types VT_DISPATCH, VT_UNKNOWN, and VT_BSTR are pointers, and do not require another level of indirection.

Which means you should remove the `&` in `(void*)&ptrActivity`.